# Using Unity instead of ASP.Net Core DI IServiceCollection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, unity-container

More and more .NET Core libraries is bound to `IServiceCollection`. In example, I want to use `HttpClientFactory` described [here](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpClientFactory/wiki/Consumption-Patterns) in my NET Framework 4.7.1. desktop application. My application is using Unity IoC. I referenced `Microsoft.Extensions.Http` as NuGet.

But there is a problem: new ASP.Net Core components are bound to Microsoft DI framework for .NetCore - `IServiceCollection`. In example, registration of `HttpClientFactory` is here:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHttpClient();
}
```

I was going deeper into [MS code](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpClientFactory) and wanted to manually register corresponding interfaces and classes to Unity. This is how services are registered by IServiceCollection:

```
services.TryAddTransient<HttpMessageHandlerBuilder, DefaultHttpMessageHandlerBuilder>();
services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpClientFactory, DefaultHttpClientFactory>();
```

This would be no problem to move this to Unity IoC, but I am stucked when I want to register `DefaultHttpMessageHandlerBuilder` and `DefaultHttpClientFactory` which have **internal** visibility. So they are not available for registration outside of MS code.

Do I have any chance how to resolve this situation?

Comment: Well, as you said, the two concrete types you are looking to use are `internal`, so that's that, you can't directly use them. Just wanted to add a thought: can you set up your Unity IOC so that it resolves `IHttpClientFactory` by in turn resolving `IHttpClientFactory` from the ASP.NET `IServiceCollection`?

Comment: I resolved this issue by using unity adapter for IServiceCollection: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51036884/245460

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Edit 7.12.2022: Unity is now deprecated, so do not use it for new projects. I replaced it with Autofac.

Based on @davidfowl answer, I have used his second solution and completed code:

These packages need to be referenced from my project (snippet from .csproj):

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http">
      <Version>2.1.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Unity.Microsoft.DependencyInjection">
      <Version>2.0.10</Version>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

And here is the test that services from ServiceCollection can be resolved from Unity container:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Unity;
using Unity.Microsoft.DependencyInjection;
using Xunit;

namespace FunctionalTests
{
    public class UnityWithHttpClientFactoryTest
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Integration of Unity container with MS ServiceCollection test
        /// </summary>
        [Fact]
        public void HttpClientCanBeCreatedByUnity()
        {
            UnityContainer unityContainer = new UnityContainer();

            ServiceCollection serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
            serviceCollection.AddHttpClient("Google", (c) =>
            {
                c.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://google.com/");
            });
            serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider(unityContainer);

            Assert.True(unityContainer.IsRegistered<IHttpClientFactory>());
            IHttpClientFactory clientFactory = unityContainer.Resolve<IHttpClientFactory>();
            HttpClient httpClient = clientFactory.CreateClient("Google");

            Assert.NotNull(httpClient);
            Assert.Equal("https://google.com/", httpClient.BaseAddress.ToString());

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Note: in case of a very minimal `.csproj`, the full `DependencyInjection` dependency might be missing. I had to add it with `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="2.2.0" />`.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. `ServiceCollection` seems to come from `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`, but I do not see a `using` in your example for this. It isn't found in Unity's package. Also there's no `AddHttpClient()` method, so I'm not sure where that's coming from.

Comment: @void.pointer Everything that you are missing is in usings directive. Check if you have appropriate NuGet packages (their version will be higher now).

Answer (score 7):

You have 2 options:

- Create a ServiceCollection, add the factory and then call BuildServiceProvider and resolve the IHttpClientFactory. There's an uber sample here https://github.com/aspnet/HttpClientFactory/blob/64ed5889635b07b61923ed5fd9c8b69c997deac0/samples/HttpClientFactorySample/Program.cs#L21.
- Use the unity adapter for `IServiceCollection` https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/.